# Which server should generate the CSR when running SSL with Apache ProxyPass

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mac-osx-server, proxypass

I have an apache 2.4 server which uses proxypass to forward SSL connections for one domain to an OSX server 5.1.5 on the same local network. I generated my CSR on the apache server and it seems to work but throws a network error when using device enrollment which complains about an invalid SSL configuration, I am able to click enroll and download a profile but then I get

> profile configuration failed - network error

The following is my vhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.xyz

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests Off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLVerifyClient none
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_xyz.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_xyz.key

        ProxyPass / https://10.0.1.36/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.0.1.36/

        ProxyPreserveHost on

        <Location "/">
                Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When visiting the domain in the browser I don't see any errors.

Are there any possible errors with my configuration?

The second server has a self signed certificate as it does not directly handle any external connections, only via proxypass on the apache server.

**Is this the right way to set up SSL with proxypass or should I have the SSL certificate be created for the second server using its CSR?**

Comment: SSL was not the issue as it turns out. I hade failed to open port 1640 in the firewall for the SCEP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a separate issue maybe--have you checked the firewall, e.g. port 1640 (SCEP).  *You could post your own answer like this as well, and then mark the question answered to help clean up the site, here.*